# GitHub throws a "GitHug failed to build pages" error, why is that?

Tags: github, repository, jekyll, build-error

Here is my repo:
https://github.com/JakeHiji/jakehiji.github.io

We are using jekyll for my class but I can't seem to commit and publish my site.  We simply followed a template filling in our own information.  I have tried deleting and editing projects and essays, copied and pasted the template and redoing my information filled in, but nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

There's a very small mistake in your `essays/smartquestions.md` page.
The value for front matter date needs correction from

```
date: 2020-1-30
```

to

```
date: 2020-01-30
```